# What source bundle file types are supported?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying an app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using [the API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_CreateApplicationVersion.html):

```
https://elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1.amazon.com/?ApplicationName=SampleApp
&SourceBundle.S3Bucket=amazonaws.com
&SourceBundle.S3Key=sample.war
...
```

My impression from reading around a bit is that Java deployments use `.war`, `.zip`s  are supported ([docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deployment.html)) and that one can use `.git` (but only with PHP or using `eb`? [doc](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AK2MFX0QHRIO/Deploying-Ruby-Applications-to-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-with-Git)).

Can I use the API to create an application version from a `.git` for a Python app? Or are `zip`s the only type supported?

(Alternatively, can I git push to AWS without using the commandline tools?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to deploy to AWS:

1. The API backend, where it is basically a .zip file referenced from S3. When deploying, the Instance will unpack and run some custom scripts (which you can override from your AMI, or via Custom Configuration Files, which are the recommended way). Note that in order to create and deploy a new version in an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment, you need three calls: upload to s3, Create Application Version, and UpdateEnvironment.
2. The git endpoint, which works like this:

   - You install the [AWS Elastic Beanstalk DevTools](http://aws.amazon.com/code/6752709412171743), and run a setup script on your git repo
   - When ran, the setup script patches your `.git/config` in order to support `git aws.push` and in particular, `git aws.remote` (which is not documented)
   - `git aws.push` simply takes your keys, builds a custom URL (git aws.remote), and does a git push -f  master
   - Once AWS receives this (url is basically `<api>/<app>/<commitid>(/<envname>)`, it creates the s3 .zip file (from the commit contents), then the application version on `<app>` for `<commitid>` and if `<envname>` is present, it also issues a UpdateEnvironment call. Your AWS ids are hashed and embedded into the URL just like all AWS calls, but sent as username / password auth tokens.

([full reference docs](http://aws.amazon.com/code/6752709412171743))

I've ported that as a Maven Plugin a few months ago, and [this file](https://bitbucket.org/aldrinleal/beanstalker/src/9ad3e6be1610/beanstalk-maven-plugin/src/main/java/br/com/ingenieux/mojo/beanstalk/bundle/FastDeployMojo.java?at=default) show how it is done in plain Java. It actually covers a lot of code (since it actually builds a custom git repo - using jgit, calculates the hashes and pushes into it)

I'm strongly considering backporting as a ant task, or perhaps simply make it work without a `pom.xml` file present, so users only use maven to do the deployment.

Historically, only the first method was supported, while the second grew up in importance. Since the second is actually far easier (in beanstalk-maven-plugin, you have to call three different methods while a simply git push does all the three), we're supporting git-based deployments, and even published an archetype for it (you see a sample project [here](https://bitbucket.org/aldrinleal/maven-elasticbeanstalk-blank/src), especially the README.md in particular).

(btw, if you're using .war files, my [elastic beanstalk plugin](http://beanstalker.ingenieux.com.br/beanstalk-maven-plugin/) support both ways, and we're actually in favor of git, since it allows us to some incremental deployments)

## So, you wanna still implement it?

There are three files I suggest you read:

- [FastDeployMojo.java](https://bitbucket.org/aldrinleal/beanstalker/src/9ad3e6be1610/beanstalk-maven-plugin/src/main/java/br/com/ingenieux/mojo/beanstalk/bundle/FastDeployMojo.java?at=default) is the main façade
- [RequestSigner](https://bitbucket.org/aldrinleal/beanstalker/src/9ad3e6be1610/beanstalk-maven-plugin/src/main/java/br/com/ingenieux/mojo/beanstalk/bundle/RequestSigner.java?at=default) does the real magic
- [This is a testcase for RequestSigner](https://bitbucket.org/aldrinleal/beanstalker/src/9ad3e6be1610/beanstalk-maven-plugin/src/test/java/br/com/ingenieux/mojo/beanstalk/bundle/RequestBuilderTest.java?at=default)

Wanna do in

- Python? I'd look for [Dulwich](http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/docs/)
- C#? The powershell version is based in it
- Ruby? The Linux is based on it
- Java? Use mine, it uses jgit

Comment: This is very helpful - thank you. Your Maven tool looks great - we're developing (and planning to release when it's stable) a similar package in Python which will automate deploying from a GitHub tag zipball. My main query was whether it was possible to use a git instead of a zipball via the API - we're trying not to use any commandline tools, but I take it the cmdline tool just does the API calls for you?

Comment: Just like I've said: You create the URL, and do a git push -f to it. If you enable the DevTools (specially in Windows, where its' Powershell + C#), you are able to peek its source. What I've did was a Pure Java approach.

In python, I'd rely in dulwich ;)

Comment: I looked at your plugin's page, but don't see anything mentioned about Git. Another thing... I don't want to deploy the state of my working tree, or even necessarily my last commit. While I could stash & checkout & build & deploy & checkout & stash pop, I'd rather be able to deploy specific commits. Perhaps some clever use of ebextensions will build on the server, change the deploy dir, and run?

Comment: ^F, look for "FastDeployMojo". This is the part of source which calls jgit directly.